# Selecting index of an array from a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get my local IP-Addresses with:

```
gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select Description,IPAddress | ?{$_.IPAddress -ne $null}
```

Now, this gives me the description (name) of the adapter, and the IPv4 address and the IPv6 address in a string array. How would I go about selecting only the IPv4 address in the Select-cmdlet? I've tried multiple things but can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: To just modify your syntax that you have right now, here's a solution.

`gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ?{$_.IPAddress -ne $null} | Select Description,@{n='IPAddress';e={$_.IpAddress[0]}}`

Comment: Hm, interesting. Thank you

Comment: From Mathias: That will give unexpected results on adapters with only IPv6 adresses

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-match` with a regex pattern that matches an IPv4 address inside a calculate property:

```
$IPv4Pattern = '^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$'
gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select Description,@{Name="IPAddress";Expr={$_.IPAddress|Where{ $_ -match $IPv4Pattern}}} | ?{$_.IPAddress -ne $null}
```